# Error while importing a CURL post to Postman

Tags: curl, postman

I am trying to import as RAW the following CURL into postman. I play around this with swagger an it works through the swagger online interface, the generated curl goes like this (credentials changed for security)

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXYYYZZZZ' 'https://backoffice.paymentiq.io/paymentiq/admin/v1/payments?merchantId=YYYYYY&txDateFrom=2020-10-01%2000%3A00%3A00'
```

But I always get the following answer

```
"Unable to import as APIs when offline. These files will be imported as collections instead. Connect to the internet to import as APIs."
```

Is there anything wrong in my procedure?

Comment: You've seen this https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9146 ?

Comment: What's the path you're navigating to do that?

Comment: Are you actually signed in / do you have a Postman account?

Comment: solved.it was a firewall blocking the connection